# PdfHanlder.ashx working on IIS Express , but not working on IIS Production Server

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, iis-express, ashx

I have developed an **ASHX file that outputs a PDF**.Everything works wonderful when I debug it on Visual Studio. If I enter the url directly from the browser it is working fine. It downloads PDF.
I have a Default.aspx that shows the PDF (from the ASHX url ) in an object html control(thats the one i am interested in)

The **problems becomes when I publish the app to a virtual directory on IIS** Production Environment. **No PDF is loaded** in Default.aspx , but if I enter the ashx url directly in the browser it downloads the PDF correctly.
What i am doing wrong? I am using IIS 5.1
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It was not fault of ASHX,the html object was referencing a bad URL for the PDF.
In Local server the URL was

- http://localhost/PdfHanlder.ashx?Id=101&.pdf

But in server it was deployed to a site "Testing"
so the url was

- http://server/Testing/PdfHanlder.ashx?Id=101&.pdf

I was referencing the pdf inside the   from
 - http://server/PdfHanlder.ashx?Id=101&.pdf
So i missed the /Testing prefix...once it gets fixed it started to works.